# How to share my calendar to every user in SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-server

I have created an overlay calendar from exchange and it is showing all details under my credentials. And if any other person open that calendar, seen nothing even appropriate permission has been provided. How to show my overlay calendar from exchange to all user in SharePoint, thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried granting permission to the OOTB group "Everyone" to this calendar/list.

Answer (score 0):

If you are overlaying the Exchange calendar you need to grant access to Everyone in Exchange.